# Constraining the drawing of a line to 45 degree angles

Tags: math, geometry, drawing, line, trigonometry

I have the start point (x1,y1) and the desired length and angle of the line.

If the angles were directions, 0 degrees is W, 90 is N, 180 is E and 270 is S. I can modify this if needed.

How can I use the start point, length and angle to determine the end point(x2, y2)?

Comment: In which direction do x and y increase? I assume x increases east, and y increases south, like on a screen? Or y increases north like in mathematics?

Comment: Yes, this is on a screen so your first assumption is correct.

Comment: It is typical to have E be 0 and increase counter-clockwise.

Comment: @Scottie:  Since `y` increases as you move *down* the screen in computer graphics, it is typical for angles to increase clockwise.  knuckfubuck has already stated that this is the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a screen:

For W = 0, N = 90, E = 180, S = 270:

```
x2 = x1 - length * cos(angle)
y2 = y1 - length * sin(angle)
```

For E = 0, N = 90, W = 180, S = 270:

```
x2 = x1 + length * cos(angle)
y2 = y1 - length * sin(angle)
```

Note that you need to make sure your implementation of cos works in degrees not radians otherwise you will get lines at strange angles.

Comment: I changed my angles to start at 0 being E and increasing counter-clockwise as specified above. Is that how it should work with this equation for the screen?

Comment: I've added an answer for both ways.

Comment: If you define E as 0 and go clockwise, then you can use `abc`s answer.

Comment: Thank you for the tip on checking into radians vs angles. That was one of the major problems with my code.

Comment: @knuckfubuck: You're welcome. I'm glad the little bit of extra info helped you. :)

Answer (score 7):

x2 = x1 + length*cos(angle)

y2 = y1 + length*sin(angle)

In this case angle is counter-clockwise increasing with 0 pointing towards positive x. The x axis is increasing to the right, and the y axis up.